# Basemaps not available in my ArcGIS 10.6.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, basemap

[image]

My ArcGIS 10.6.1 has only 6 basemaps, it doesn't have the gray basemap etc.

Comment: Is ArcMap signed in to ArcGIS Online?  If so, sign out and then try again (perhaps after restarting ArcMap).  I'm not sure if ArcMap's basemap gallery is defined by your ArcGIS Online basemap gallery (have never tested this), so this may be worth a try.

Comment: I tried by logging in and out of arcgis online and restarted arcgis, but still the basemaps are not available.